# Recursively doing the command ls without -R

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to find a way to recreate the output of `ls -R` (linux) without using the option `-R` i.e without the recursion command, is this at all possible?

There are no other constraints.

Comment: Reproduce it exactly? Why the restriction? What do you plan to do with the output?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs at unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
printf "%s\n" **
```

or

```
find .
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but the output doesn't look exactly like `ls -R`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of right now is to recurse through all given directories using `find` and to perform a listing on each. I used `ls -1` because I noticed that `ls -R` defaults to a single column when redirected into a file; you may choose to omit the `-1` option.

```
for dir in `find . -type d`; do
    echo $dir:
    ls -1 $dir
done
```

However, it doesn't work with filenames that contain spaces. I'm still looking for a way around that...